# How to display HTML from response as HTML in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

I have n number of records coming from backend as HTML in array. I need to display the HTML response as HTML in my view. I tried `ng-bind-html` , but it takes the last value. Need assistance.

```
  $scope.res=  "data": [
            {
              "jd": "<p>this jd1</p>"
            },
            {
              "jd": "<li>this jd2</li>"
            },
            {
              "jd": "<ul>this jd3</ul>"
            },
            {
              "jd": "<p>this jd4</p>"
            }
          ]
        }
```

Html:

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in res">
    <div ng-bind-html ="item.jd">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use $sce.trustAsHtml. See the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce).

What you could do is:

Add this line in your controller:

```
$scope.trustAsHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml;
```

And update your HTML like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html ="trustAsHtml(item.jd)">
```

Note that you should probably start using Angular 6 instead of AngularJS

Comment: Hi , sure will do it. I have one more query. I am doing encoding and sending the html response to backend. Now I need to decode them and use it here. So I wrote a filter.         DecodeFilter:   app.filter('decodeFilter', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return decodeURIComponent(unescape(input));
    };
});